# Change language on wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, internationalization

Im trying to create a button in my wordpress theme that changes the sites language. I have followed the guide (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization), created filed in poedit etc and loaded the text-domain in functions.php.

But how can i now change the language on the site?

functions.php

```
public function theme_supports() {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'marcial', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}
```

style.css

```
/**
* Theme Name: marcial
* Description: lorem ipsum
* Author: lorem ipsum
* Text Domain: marcial
* Domain Path: /languages
*/
```

header.php (render test), it works

```
__('hello', 'marcial')
```

It prints what in my pot-file. But how can i change language?

Comment: Mathias5,  Admins can already change the language in the settings. Why would you replicate that?   

If you particularly want the button in your theme settings, then you should have it update the WPLANG option in wp_options and wordpress will handle all the translation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way i try before :

Multilingual WordPress Site (Human Translation)

1- install and activate the [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) plugin.

2- The language settings page is divided into three tabs. The first tab is labeled ‘Languages’. This is where you add the languages you want to use on your site.

3- After adding the languages, switch to the ‘Strings Translations’ tab. Here you need to translate site title, description, and then choose the date and time format.

4- Last step in the configuration is the Settings tab. This is where you can choose a default language for your site and other technical settings.

Polylang makes it super easy to add content in different languages. Simply create a new post/page or edit an existing one. On the post edit screen, you will notice the languages meta box.

Or you can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/ so easy also